# Car shuts off while driving

Tags: starting, cranks-wont-run, accent

This is a 2005 Hyundai Accent 1.6.

I was driving and the car just shut off. Engine will turn over but will not start. Checked for spark and fuel and it has both.

Comment: How’s compression and injector pulse?

Comment: Have you read the codes?

Comment: Timing is off? Did it overheat when it died? How did the plugs look? Despite having fuel have you tried starting fluid?